# install-man5 Error 1 after running 'make install' after compiling NUT (Network UPS Tools)

Tags: linux, make, nut

In an attempt to solve my [NUT energy-saving problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/648389/how-to-disable-ups-energy-saving-with-nut-ups-ignorantly-powering-itself-off-wi) that I've asked about in a lengthy serverfault question, I read that in the latest NUT version, nutdriver_qx replaces blazer_ser and I think it's worth trying nutdriver_qx as it might allow me to disable energy-saving on my UPS.

I've followed these steps to [compile Network UPS Tools](http://www.enlightenmentfun.com/ups-for-linux-server-desktop-getting-supported-models-and-noname-brands-working-on-debian-ubuntu/) and have successfully compiled it, I have drivers/nutdriver_qx binary afterwards. I've tried copying the binary into `/lib/nut` but that didn't work. So now I'm trying make `make install` (**as root**) but got stuck with some error relating to manuals or something?

```
make install
Making install in include
make[1]: Entering directory `/nut-master/include'
NUT_VERSION: "2.7.2.5"
test -f nut_version.h || cp _nut_version.h nut_version.h
cmp -s _nut_version.h nut_version.h || cp _nut_version.h nut_version.h
rm -f _nut_version.h
make  install-am
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/include'
make[3]: Entering directory `/nut-master/include'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/include'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/include'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/include'
Making install in common
make[1]: Entering directory `/nut-master/common'
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/common'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/common'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/common'
Making install in clients
make[1]: Entering directory `/nut-master/clients'
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/clients'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/ups/lib'
 /bin/bash ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libupsclient.la libnutclient.la '/usr/local/ups/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libupsclient.so.4.0.0 /usr/local/ups/lib/libupsclient.so.4.0.0
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/ups/lib && { ln -s -f libupsclient.so.4.0.0 libupsclient.so.4 || { rm -f libupsclient.so.4 && ln -s libupsclient.so.4.0.0 libupsclient.so.4; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/ups/lib && { ln -s -f libupsclient.so.4.0.0 libupsclient.so || { rm -f libupsclient.so && ln -s libupsclient.so.4.0.0 libupsclient.so; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libupsclient.lai /usr/local/ups/lib/libupsclient.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libnutclient.so.0.0.0 /usr/local/ups/lib/libnutclient.so.0.0.0
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/ups/lib && { ln -s -f libnutclient.so.0.0.0 libnutclient.so.0 || { rm -f libnutclient.so.0 && ln -s libnutclient.so.0.0.0 libnutclient.so.0; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/ups/lib && { ln -s -f libnutclient.so.0.0.0 libnutclient.so || { rm -f libnutclient.so && ln -s libnutclient.so.0.0.0 libnutclient.so; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libnutclient.lai /usr/local/ups/lib/libnutclient.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libupsclient.a /usr/local/ups/lib/libupsclient.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/local/ups/lib/libupsclient.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/local/ups/lib/libupsclient.a
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libnutclient.a /usr/local/ups/lib/libnutclient.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/local/ups/lib/libnutclient.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/local/ups/lib/libnutclient.a
libtool: finish: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/local/ups/lib
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/ups/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/ups/bin'
  /bin/bash ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c upsc upslog upsrw upscmd '/usr/local/ups/bin'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/upsc /usr/local/ups/bin/upsc
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/upslog /usr/local/ups/bin/upslog
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/upsrw /usr/local/ups/bin/upsrw
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/upscmd /usr/local/ups/bin/upscmd
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/ups/bin'
 /usr/bin/install -c upssched-cmd '/usr/local/ups/bin'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/ups/sbin'
  /bin/bash ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c upsmon upssched '/usr/local/ups/sbin'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/upsmon /usr/local/ups/sbin/upsmon
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c upssched /usr/local/ups/sbin/upssched
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/clients'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/clients'
Making install in conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/nut-master/conf'
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/conf'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/ups/etc'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 upsd.conf.sample upsd.users.sample nut.conf.sample ups.conf.sample '/usr/local/ups/etc'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/ups/etc'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 upssched.conf.sample upsmon.conf.sample '/usr/local/ups/etc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/conf'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/conf'
Making install in data
make[1]: Entering directory `/nut-master/data'
Making install in html
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/data/html'
make[3]: Entering directory `/nut-master/data/html'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/data/html'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/data/html'
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/data'
make[3]: Entering directory `/nut-master/data'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/ups/share'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 cmdvartab '/usr/local/ups/share'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/ups/share'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 driver.list '/usr/local/ups/share'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/data'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/data'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/data'
Making install in tools
make[1]: Entering directory `/nut-master/tools'
Making install in .
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/tools'
make[3]: Entering directory `/nut-master/tools'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/tools'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/tools'
Making install in nut-scanner
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/tools/nut-scanner'
make  install-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/nut-master/tools/nut-scanner'
make[4]: Entering directory `/nut-master/tools/nut-scanner'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/ups/lib'
 /bin/bash ../../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libnutscan.la '/usr/local/ups/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libnutscan.so.1.0.0 /usr/local/ups/lib/libnutscan.so.1.0.0
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/ups/lib && { ln -s -f libnutscan.so.1.0.0 libnutscan.so.1 || { rm -f libnutscan.so.1 && ln -s libnutscan.so.1.0.0 libnutscan.so.1; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/ups/lib && { ln -s -f libnutscan.so.1.0.0 libnutscan.so || { rm -f libnutscan.so && ln -s libnutscan.so.1.0.0 libnutscan.so; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libnutscan.lai /usr/local/ups/lib/libnutscan.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libnutscan.a /usr/local/ups/lib/libnutscan.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/local/ups/lib/libnutscan.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/local/ups/lib/libnutscan.a
libtool: finish: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/local/ups/lib
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/ups/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/ups/bin'
  /bin/bash ../../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c nut-scanner '/usr/local/ups/bin'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/nut-scanner /usr/local/ups/bin/nut-scanner
make[4]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/tools/nut-scanner'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/tools/nut-scanner'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/tools/nut-scanner'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/tools'
Making install in docs
make[1]: Entering directory `/nut-master/docs'
Making install in man
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/docs/man'
Using existing nut.conf.5 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing ups.conf.5 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upsd.conf.5 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upsd.users.5 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upsmon.conf.5 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upssched.conf.5 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing nutupsdrv.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upsc.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upscmd.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upsd.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upsdrvctl.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upslog.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upsmon.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upsrw.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upssched.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing nut-scanner.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing nut-recorder.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing al175.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing apcsmart.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing apcsmart-old.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing bcmxcp.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing belkin.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing belkinunv.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing bestfortress.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing bestuferrups.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing bestups.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing bestfcom.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing blazer_ser.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing clone.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing dummy-ups.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing etapro.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing everups.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing gamatronic.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing genericups.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing isbmex.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing ivtscd.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing liebert.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing liebert-esp2.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing masterguard.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing metasys.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing mge-shut.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing mge-utalk.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing nutdrv_qx.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing oneac.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing microdowell.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing optiups.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing powercom.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing powerpanel.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing rhino.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing riello_ser.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing safenet.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing solis.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing tripplite.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing tripplitesu.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upscode2.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing victronups.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing apcupsd-ups.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
make[3]: Entering directory `/nut-master/docs/man'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
Using existing nut.conf.5 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing ups.conf.5 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upsd.conf.5 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upsd.users.5 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upsmon.conf.5 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upssched.conf.5 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/ups/share/man/man5'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./nut.conf.5 ./ups.conf.5 ./upsd.conf.5 ./upsd.users.5 ./upsmon.conf.5 ./upssched.conf.5 '/usr/local/ups/share/man/man5'
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat `./nut.conf.5': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat `./ups.conf.5': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat `./upsd.conf.5': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat `./upsd.users.5': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat `./upsmon.conf.5': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat `./upssched.conf.5': No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [install-man5] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/docs/man'
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/docs/man'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/docs'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

in response to a comment, the make command runs without errors

```
$ make
Making all in include
make[1]: Entering directory `/nut-master/include'
NUT_VERSION: "2.7.2.5"
test -f nut_version.h || cp _nut_version.h nut_version.h
cmp -s _nut_version.h nut_version.h || cp _nut_version.h nut_version.h
rm -f _nut_version.h
make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/include'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/include'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/include'
Making all in common
make[1]: Entering directory `/nut-master/common'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/common'
Making all in clients
make[1]: Entering directory `/nut-master/clients'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/clients'
Making all in conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/nut-master/conf'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/conf'
Making all in data
make[1]: Entering directory `/nut-master/data'
Making all in html
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/data/html'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/data/html'
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/data'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/data'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/data'
Making all in tools
make[1]: Entering directory `/nut-master/tools'
Making all in .
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/tools'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/tools'
Making all in nut-scanner
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/tools/nut-scanner'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/nut-master/tools/nut-scanner'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/tools/nut-scanner'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/tools/nut-scanner'
Regenerating the SNMP helper files.
Regenerating the USB helper files.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/tools'
Making all in docs
make[1]: Entering directory `/nut-master/docs'
Making all in man
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/docs/man'
Using existing nut.conf.5 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing ups.conf.5 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upsd.conf.5 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upsd.users.5 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upsmon.conf.5 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upssched.conf.5 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing nutupsdrv.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upsc.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upscmd.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upsd.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upsdrvctl.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upslog.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upsmon.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upsrw.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upssched.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing nut-scanner.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing nut-recorder.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing al175.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing apcsmart.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing apcsmart-old.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing bcmxcp.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing belkin.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing belkinunv.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing bestfortress.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing bestuferrups.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing bestups.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing bestfcom.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing blazer_ser.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing clone.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing dummy-ups.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing etapro.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing everups.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing gamatronic.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing genericups.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing isbmex.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing ivtscd.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing liebert.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing liebert-esp2.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing masterguard.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing metasys.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing mge-shut.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing mge-utalk.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing nutdrv_qx.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing oneac.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing microdowell.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing optiups.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing powercom.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing powerpanel.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing rhino.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing riello_ser.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing safenet.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing solis.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing tripplite.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing tripplitesu.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing upscode2.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing victronups.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
Using existing apcupsd-ups.8 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/docs/man'
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/docs'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/docs'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/docs'
Making all in drivers
make[1]: Entering directory `/nut-master/drivers'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/drivers'
Making all in lib
make[1]: Entering directory `/nut-master/lib'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/lib'
Making all in scripts
make[1]: Entering directory `/nut-master/scripts'
Making all in augeas
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/scripts/augeas'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/scripts/augeas'
Making all in devd
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/scripts/devd'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/scripts/devd'
Making all in hotplug
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/scripts/hotplug'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/scripts/hotplug'
Making all in python
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/scripts/python'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/scripts/python'
Making all in systemd
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/scripts/systemd'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/scripts/systemd'
Making all in udev
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/scripts/udev'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/scripts/udev'
Making all in Solaris
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/scripts/Solaris'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/scripts/Solaris'
make[2]: Entering directory `/nut-master/scripts'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/scripts'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/scripts'
Making all in server
make[1]: Entering directory `/nut-master/server'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/server'
Making all in tests
make[1]: Entering directory `/nut-master/tests'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nut-master/tests'
make[1]: Entering directory `/nut-master'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/nut-master'
```

Comment: Probably the actual error has happened during `make` and not `make install` phase. I guess your system is lacking so documentation/man page related dev tools.

Comment: Hi Janne, thanks for your reply. The make command runs without errors. I've updated my question with the output of the make command.

Comment: OK, replied to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the `make` output is full of this kind of lines:

```
Using existing nut.conf.5 manual page, since 'asciidoc', 'xmllint' or 'xsltproc' were not found.
```

... I would install `asciidoc`, `xmllint` and `xsltproc`, then run `make clean` and finally `make && make install` to see if the man pages get generated.

Now it seems to "use existing files" but apparently they are nowhere to be found.